# How to search an XML Tag or a JSON Key in Marklogic using Java API

Tags: xml, json, marklogic, java

I need to search  an XML tag or a JSON key in Marklogic Database using Java API  without specifying any element value for XML tag or value for JSON key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Java API, you can use the containerQuery() method of the StructuredQueryBuilder class to match the JSON property or XML element.

Supply an empty and() for the contained query to match anything within the container, as in:

```
qb.containerQuery(qb.jsonProperty("name"), qb.and())
```

For more information, see:

http://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/query/StructuredQueryBuilder.html#containerQuery%28com.marklogic.client.query.StructuredQueryBuilder.ContainerIndex,%20com.marklogic.client.query.StructuredQueryDefinition%29

If you want to extract only those elements, you can persist query options with the  that specifies which elements or properties to extract from the documents:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/appendixb#id_18313

You might want to consume the search response with a JSON or XML handle instead of using the SearchHandle class.

Hoping that helps

Comment: Can you give me the full code from Database Connection configuration to displaying the result in JAVA Eclipse Console

Comment: Take a look at

https://github.com/marklogic/java-client-api/blob/master/src/main/java/com/marklogic/client/example/cookbook/StructuredSearch.java#L113-L114

Other than the highlighted lines, most of the rest of your code should be similar.

Comment: Thanks for the code.It satisfies my requirement.But I need to get only the values for my JSON Key which i am using for my search and not the snippet or entire document.For eg:- {"colour":"red","type":"good"} , {"colour":"blue","type":"bad"} are 2 JSON Documents then if I search for "colour" key it should search for that particular key in these Docs and I should be able to get only the value's of the Search Keys in the result handle

Comment: If you only want the specific searched value, you can send a combined query with query options that specify <extract-document-data> http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/appendixb#id_18313  (or, in MarkLogic 7.x, <extract-metadata>) and <transform-results apply="empty">.

Answer (score 0):

You can use path indexes if you don't want to discriminate between no-namespace elements and json-properties with the same name. Otherwise use fields.

If you want to search for just presence of elements or json-properties instead of for specific values, you should use an element-query search constraint:

http://docs.marklogic.com/search:search#opt-constraint

> ```
> <element-query>
> ```
>
> Specifies a constraint that restricts the search to the specified
>   element. You cannot create facets from an element-query constraint.
>
> ```
> <options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
>   <constraint name="sample-element-constraint">
>     <element-query name="title" ns="http://my/namespace" />
>   </constraint>
> </options>
> ```

Not tested against JSON properties, but MarkLogic 8 often treats them in the same way.

HTH!

Comment: What  I actually want is to search for a JSON Key/XML Element and to get the value for that searched XML Element /JSON Key from the XML or JSON Document.Is this possible with the JAVA Client Api for Marklogic